# Using list of scattered points in 2D tilemap, how would I find the center of those points?

Tags: algorithm, search, location, point

Have a look at this image for example (just a random image of scattered points from image search):

[image]

<sup>([reference](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Exoplanet_Period-Mass_Scatter.png))</sup>

You'll see the locations with blue points. Let's say the blue represents what I'm looking for. But I want to find the coordinates where there is the most blue. Meaning the most dense or center of most points (in the picture, it would approximate [.5, .5]).

If I have an arrayList of each and every blue point (x,y coordinates), then how do I use those points to find the center/most dense area of those points?

Comment: what is size of the set of points ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options, dependent on what precisely you need.  The simplest would be the [mean, the average of all points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value):  You sum all points up and divide by their number. 
  Getting the *most dense* area is complicated, because at first you have to come up with a definition of "dense".  One option would be:  For each point P, find the 7 nearest neighbors N_P1...N_P7.  The point P where the 7th neighbor has the smallest distance |P-N_P7| is the point with the highest density around it and you pick P as center.  You can replace that 7 with any number that works for you.  You could even replace it with some parameter from your data set, say 1/3 of the total number of points.

Comment: That's the simplest way and I did need a simple solution so thank you. I'll add all the x's and y's of each location and then in the end, divide by the number of locations. Thanks again!